# Select event on JQuery UI autocompleter is not fired

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am trying to use the jQuery UI, but I can't seem to figure out how to get the select event to execute.

I bind the autocompleter as following:

```
$().ready(function () {
    $("#txtPersonSearch").autocomplete({
        source: '<%=Url.Action("GetPeople") %>',
        minLength: 3,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            // This code is never reached
            console.log(ui);
        }
    });
});
```

Am I missing something to be able to bind to the select event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe your controller action throws an exception. Let's take the following action:

```
public ActionResult GetPeople(string term)
{
    // the term parameter will contain the search string
    // TODO: use the term parameter to filter the results from 
    // your repository. In this example the result is hardcoded
    // to verify that the everything works.
    return Json(new[]
    {
        new { id = "1", label = "label 1", value = "value 1" },
        new { id = "2", label = "label 2", value = "value 2" },
        new { id = "3", label = "label 3", value = "value 3" },
    }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Things to watch out for:

- The controller action is accessible with GET verb (`JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet`)
- The controller action returns a JSON array where each item has an id, label and value properties
- The controller action doesn't throw an exception

And then:

```
$(function () {
    $('#txtMovieSearch').autocomplete({
        source: '<%= Url.Action("GetPeople") %>',
        minLength: 3,
        select: function (evt, ui) {
            console.log(ui);
        }
    });
});
```

And finally use [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) to analyze what exactly is sent to your server as an AJAX request and the response from the server.

Comment: You were right! It worked with a more simple JSON return. My Controller returns a Dictionary<int,string> is there trouble serializing it to JSON?

Comment: Look at my example. There won't be trouble serializing the dictionary, but there will be trouble for the plugin understanding the response. It needs to be formatted as in my example. So using the simple `.Select()` extension method on your dictionary will allow you to achieve the desired result: `return Json(dico.Select(x => new { id = x.Key, label = x.Value, value = x.Value }), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`